# Flutter NFC-Manager: Most of credit/ debit card cannot be read on iOS

Tags: flutter, dart, nfc

On iOS devices, some contactless Credit/ Debit cards cannot be read. However, Android devices can read all cards.
Any help will be appreciated :)

```
NfcManager.instance.startSession(
  onDiscover:(NfcTaf tag) async {
    // Go to next page
   NfcManager.instance.stopSession
  }
)
```

I use Flutter NFC Manager to implement the Tag reading feature. On an iOS device, ready to scan window pop up but cannot read some cards…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS NFC [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc) says:-

> Core NFC doesn't support payment-related Application IDs.

Apple don't want you to read contactless Credit/ Debit cards, they reserve that capability to themselves.